# What is the likely source of unexpected clones of newly opened GitHub repo?

Tags: clone, github

This is a soft-question in that the answer will necessarily either include a probabilistic break-down of likely sources, or it will be speculative.

However, I am curious to know what automated (bots), possibly exploitative or other sources can be behind some 10 clones over the course of 1 or 2 hours of a newly created GitHub repository without any followers, forks or name recognition of the account.

The clones came at different times (no clusters) from very different countries. No URL was attached to them, or recorded.

The number of views was very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### GitHub is under attack.

#### Yup. Clones of public repos that somehow bundle in malicious payloads is a (sadly) thing.

Read this from *Ars Technics*: “[GitHub besieged by millions of malicious repositories in ongoing attack](https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/02/github-besieged-by-millions-of-malicious-repositories-in-ongoing-attack/)”; bold emphasis is mine:

> “GitHub is struggling to contain an ongoing attack that’s flooding the site with millions of code repositories. **These repositories contain obfuscated malware that steals passwords and cryptocurrency from developer devices, researchers said.**”
>
> “The malicious repositories are clones of legitimate ones, making them hard to distinguish to the casual eye. **An unknown party has automated a process that forks legitimate repositories, meaning the source code is copied so developers can use it in an independent project that builds on the original one. The result is millions of forks with names identical to the original one that add a payload that’s wrapped under seven layers of obfuscation.** To make matters worse, some people, unaware of the malice of these imitators, are forking the forks, which adds to the flood.”

The technique is known as “[repo confusion](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/dependency-confusion/)” and the idea is to deceive future users: A new user slightly misspells the repo and clones one that has malicious code in it. The repo technically works, but if it part of a juicy project of some kind, it can do all kinds of nasty things.

Heck, if you have a popular project that is well known, like “Cool Code Repo”, and someone does a Google search you could end up on the malicious code’s repo without even knowing.

All kinds or horrible things can happen! But apparently GitHub is attempting to deal with it:

> “GitHub hosts over 100M developers building across over 420M repositories, and is committed to providing a safe and secure platform for developers. We have teams dedicated to detecting, analyzing, and removing content and accounts that violate our Acceptable Use Policies. We employ manual reviews and at-scale detections that use machine learning and constantly evolve and adapt to adversarial tactics. We also encourage customers and community members to report abuse and spam.”

If you have the ability (aka: paid for it) I would encourage you to make your GitHub repos private for now. If you can’t? I don’t know what to say other than “Be careful!”